# Is there a simple way to convert the value to integer?

Tags: python-3.x, input, type-conversion, integer

```
a,b,c=input().split()
a=int(a)
b=int(b)
c=int(c)
```

for the above code is there a simple way to take in data within a single line and space-separated directly as integers? Thanks in advance

Comment: `a, b, c = map(int, input().split())`

Comment: I have tested this and it seems to be running an infinite loop. I am able to enter more than a single row of elements using this bit of code, I guess this isn't serving the purpose that I wanted.

Comment: Nope, it definitely works. This is how you get multiple integers in one line.

Comment: I have seen the same syntax online but it seems to give me a problem. It takes in infinite number of input or please let me know if there is a specific way to give input. I simply type in 3 integer values with space in between them and my prompt never execute the instructions that follow this line and give the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to use the `map` method as @Asocia suggested and the code snippet is given below

```py
a, b , c = map(int,input().split())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def main(string):
    arr = []
    while string.count(', ') > 0:
        index = string.index(', ')
        arr.append(int(string[0:index]))
        string = string[index + 2:len(string)]
    arr.append(int(string))
    return arr
print(main('1, 2, -3, 7592'))
```

This works by checking for a comma and a space (The indication of a new element) and adds each element to the array without the spacing as well as converting it to an integer.

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From Review.